# Identifying a substring in Python (moving along indices within a string) - can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, substring, concatenation, indices

I'm new to Python and coding and stuck at comparing a substring to another string.

I've got:
string sq and pattern STR.

Goal: I'm trying to count the max number of STR pattern appearing in that string in a row.

This is part of the code:

```
 STR = key
        counter = 0
        maximum = 0

        for i in sq:
            while sq[i:i+len(STR)] == STR:
                counter += 1
                i += len(STR)
```

The problem seems to appear in the "while part", saying TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

I see it treats *i* as a character and *len(STR)* as an int, but I don't get how to fix this.
The idea is to take the first substring equal to the length of STR and figure out whether this substring and STR pattern are identical.

Thank you!

Comment: Is `sq.count(key)` what you want?  It will count occurrences of `key` in `sq`.

Comment: As far as I know, this will count total, right?  and I need to count it in a row (consecutively)

Comment: You have some confusion over whether `i` is supposed to be an _element_ of `sq`, or an _index_ in `sq`. And you should not assign to a loop variable inside the loop.

Comment: @alaniwi yes, that's right, I aim it to be  an index (like in C language), and in Python it's an element by default, how do I fix it?

Comment: Give some input/output examples of what you want.  It isn't clear.  How many do you want for `abcabcdefabcabcabc` for key = `abc`? 2 or 3?

Comment: @MarkTolonen Suppose there is a string AAABBBAAABAACCCAAAAAA, and I've got a pattern AAA. Eventually I need to count the max number of the pattern going consecutively. In this string it will be 2. For this, I'm taking the first substring equal to the length of the pattern, and check whether they are identical or not.

Comment: @MarkTolonen 3 in your example, as 3 is max of abc going consecutively

Comment: one liner: `max(len(n)//len(key) for n in re.findall(rf'(?:{re.escape(key)})+',sq))`

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks! could you please clarify or comment a little on how main parts of it work? this looks quite cryptic to me, and I think I'm not that advanced yet:)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Cryptic one-liners are not particularly helpful for learning purposes for somebody new to Python, even if they have the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping using:

```
for i in sq:
```

you are looping over the *elements* of `sq`.

If instead you want the variable `i` to loop over the possible *indexes* of `sq`, you would generally loop over `range(len(sq))`, so that you get values from `0` to `len(sq) - 1`.

```
for i in range(len(sq)):
```

However, in this case you are wanting to assign to `i` inside the loop:

```
i += len(STR)
```

This will not have the desired effect if you are looping over `range(...)` because on the next iteration it will be assigned to the next value from `range`, ignoring the increment that was added.  In general one should not assign to a loop variable inside the loop.

So it would probably most easily be implemented with a `while` loop, and you set the desired value of `i` explicitly (`i=0` to initialise, `i+=1` before restarting the loop), and then you can have whatever other assignments you want inside the loop.

```
STR = "ell"
sq = "well, well, hello world"

counter = 0

i = 0
while i < len(sq):
    while sq[i:i+len(STR)] == STR:  # re use of while here, see comments
        counter += 1
        i += len(STR)
    i += 1

print(counter)  # prints 3
```

(You could perhaps save `len(sq)` and `len(STR)` in other variables to save evaluating them repeatedly.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's super useful to know and clarifies the confusion! The only thing bothering me: I need to count the pattern consecutively. So the idea is that if the pattern is identical, I move forward by its length (i += len(STR)), so I guess it should be WHILE sq[i:i+len(STR)] == STR:, is that correct?

Comment: @Sabie - yes, that would work, sorry I didn't note that requirement (I will edit this) - note that no check would be done in inner `while` loop that we are not going beyond `len(sq)` but it will still work because the slice `sq[i:i+len(STR)]` is still a valid operation even if it is out of bounds (it may produce an empty string)

Answer (score 1):

This solution doesn't use a `for` so the increment can be by one on a non-match and by string length on a match.  Any non-match records the maximum count seen so far and resets the count.

```
def count_max(string,key):

    if len(key) > len(string):
        return 0

    last = len(string) - len(key)
    i = 0
    count = 0
    maximum = 0

    while i <= last:
        if string[i:i+len(key)] == key:
            count += 1
            i += len(key)
        else:
            maximum = max(maximum,count)
            count = 0
            i += 1
    return max(maximum,count)

key = 'abc'
strings = 'ab','abc','ababcabc','abcdefabcabc','abcabcdefabc'

for string in strings:
    print(count_max(string,key))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
2
2
```

Here also is a potentially faster version.  For short strings it isn't faster, but will be much faster if the strings are very long since the regular expression will find matches much faster than Python loops.

```
def count_max2(string,key):
    return max([len(match) // len(key)
                for match in re.findall(rf'(?:{re.escape(key)})+',string)]
               ,default=0)
```

How it works:

- [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) is a function to make sure characters in `key` are taken literally and are not regular expression syntax.  Allows searching for `+` for example, instead of being treated as a "one or more" match.
- `rf''` is syntax for a raw [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) (format string).  "raw" is recommended for regular expressions because some syntax for expressions is confused with other Python syntax.  f-strings allow variables and functions to be inserted into strings with curly braces `{}`.
- `re.findall` finds all consecutive matches in the string.
- `[f(x) for x in iterable]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and takes the list returned from iterable and computes a function on each item in the list.  In this case, if takes the length of the match divided by the length of the key to get the number of occurrences of the key.
- `max(iterable,default=0)` returns the maximum value of iterable, or 0 if the iterable is empty (no matches).